# pandas DataFrameで特定条件で選択した行から指定のカラムだけ取得したい

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなpandas DataFrameがあります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(30).reshape(10,3),columns=pd.Index(['one','two','three']))
```

特定条件で選択した行は以下のように簡単に取得できます。
例えば、twoカラムの10より大きい数の行を取得するには以下のようにしています。

```
df[df['two']>10]
```

しかし本当に欲しいのはこの条件で取得したDataFrameのthreeカラムだけを取得したいです。
簡単に一行で取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
df2 = df[df['two']>10]
df3 = df2['three']
```

とすれば取得可能ですが、もっとスマートにしたいです。１行で書けないものでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `df[df['two']>10]['three']` でよろしいかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pandasは奥深いですね。いろんな書き方があるのですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常はこのように書くことが多いです。

```
df.loc[df["two"] > 10, "three"]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。